# Create variables by multiplying variables that have the same name suffix

Tags: stata

I  have a Stata dataset that looks like this:

| stock8201 | stock8202 | stock8203 | immigrantshare8201 | immigrantshare8202 | immigrantshare8203 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 24 | 21 | 0.0004696 | 0.0001165 | 0.0016181 |
| 123 | 24 | 21 | 0.0004696 | 0.0001165 | 0.0016181 |
| 123243 | 24 | 21 | 0.0004696 | 0.0001165 | 0.0016181 |

And I want a command that would create for me three variables that would multiply the first one stock8201 by immigrantshare8201 and do the same for the other ones. The table I want at the end would look something like this:

| Predi8201 | Predi8202 | Predi8203 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.0577608 | 0.002796 | 0.0339801 |
| 0.0577608 | 0.002796 | 0.0339801 |
| 57.8749128 | 0.002796 | 0.0339801 |

which is for instance: `Predi8201` which is equal to `stock8201*immigrantshare8201`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
forval j = 1/3 { 
    gen Predi820`j' = stock820`j' * immigrantshare820`j' 
}
```

For a larger set of variables, you might want something like

```
foreach v of var stock* { 
     local suffix : subinstr local v "stock" "" 
     gen Predi`suffix' = `v' * immigrantshare`suffix' 
}
```

Your question hints that you are holding data for different months (January 1982, February 1982, ...)  in a wide layout. In Stata most things are easier in a long layout, which usually calls for `reshape long`.